# Not able to create notebook and transfer files in evernote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, evernote

I am developing a web application and I need to create an EverNote notebook and transfer some files in it.

I am able to authenticate user from EverNote but not able to create notebook. I'm also confused how to transfer files in that notebook.

Here is the authentication code. [API URL](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/NoteStore.html)

For creating a notebook:

```
noteStore.createNotebook(access_token.token, "my_notebook")
```

Error:

```
An error occurred: undefined method `write' for "my_notebook":String
```

**edit**

following seth's lead

```
      notebook = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook.new()
          notebook.name = "my_notebook3"
          x= noteStore.createNotebook(access_token.token, notebook)
         note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new()
         note.notebookGuid = x.guid
         note.title="my note"
         y=noteStore.createNote(access_token.token,note)
```

working on file transfer in that note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is a Notebook structure, not a string. You need to do something like:

```
notebook = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook.new()
notebook.name = "my_notebook"
noteStore.createNotebook(access_token.token, notebook)
```

Evernote notebooks contain only Notes, and Notes can have files attached to them. To attach a file to a new note, you need to create a Resource and include it in the note:

```
filename = # the file that you want to attach
image = File.open(filename, "rb") { |io| io.read }
hashFunc = Digest::MD5.new
hashHex = hashFunc.hexdigest(image)

data = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Data.new()
data.size = image.size
data.bodyHash = hashHex
data.body = image

resource = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Resource.new()
resource.mime = # the appropriate MIME type
resource.data = data
resource.attributes = Evernote::EDAM::Type::ResourceAttributes.new()
resource.attributes.fileName = filename

note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new()
note.title = "Title"
note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
  '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">' +
  '<en-note>' +
  '<en-media type="' + resource.mime + '" hash="' + hashHex + '"/>' +
  '</en-note>'
note.resources = [ resource ]

createdNote = noteStore.createNote(authToken, note)
```

The sample code in the Evernote API ZIP file demonstrates this. You can download the ZIP from http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/.

Comment: and how can transfer files in that notebook? I need to transfer multiple files.

Comment: The op specifically said he wants to transfer multiple files. This will only work for attachments embedded as content.